# How to pass variables to an SSIS package from a C# application

Tags: c#, ssis

Basically i am trying to build an application that uses SSIS to run a series of sql stuff.

Here is my code thus far:

```
        public JsonResult FireSSIS()
    {
        string x = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            Application app = new Application();                
            Package package = null;

            package = app.LoadPackage(@"C:\ft\Package.dtsx", null);

            Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult results = package.Execute();
            if (results == Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure)
            {
                foreach (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsError local_DtsError in package.Errors)
                {
                    x += string.Concat("Package Execution results: {0}", local_DtsError.Description.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        catch (DtsException ex)
        {
           // Exception = ex.Message;
        }
        return Json(x, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Does anybody know how to pass a variable to the package itself in this way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try that:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.RunTime.Variables myVars = package.Variables;

myVars["MyVariable1"].Value = "value1";
myVars["MyVariable2"].Value = "value2";

Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult results = package.Execute(null, myVars, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to use the [`Package.Variables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.variables.aspx) property.

```
        Package package = null;
        package = app.LoadPackage(@"C:\ft\Package.dtsx", null);
        package.Variables["User::varParam"].Value = "param value";
```