# Calling a ssis package using c# windows form(containing variable to be passed in the ssis package)

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a SSIS PACKAGE. I have designed a windows  form containing label, textbox and button to call ssis. But i am stuck for a scenario.
Like suppose i have 5 variables in ssis out of which a variable name say account number need to get from windows form textbox.

My code for the textbox is

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox objTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
        string theText = objTextBox.Text;
        string pkgLocation;
        Package pkg = null;
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app;
        DTSExecResult pkgResults;
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables myVars = pkg.Variables;

        pkgLocation =
        @"C:\Users\Visual Studio 2008\Projects" +
        @"\Integration Services Project1\xyz.dtsx";
        app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
        pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);

        myVars["Account_number"].Value = theText;

        pkgResults = pkg.Execute(null, myVars,null,null,null);
    }
```

Here the issue is when enter just one digit say 9 in window form it will start executing the package.Here i actually wanted to let user enter the full account_Number and run the package on button click.

Please let me know what is the issue in the code or what should i add in order to take the account_number on button click?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098677/how-to-pass-variables-to-an-ssis-package-from-a-c-sharp-application

Comment: @ElectricRouge i have tried the all possible solutions mentioned in that link.Code is not working :(

Comment: Post your code and the error you are getting someone might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing your code in `textBox1_TextChanged` event that's why your code is executing everytime you type a letter or digit in textbox. Everytime you type something in textbox  `TextChanged` event is fired.

Instead if you want the code to execute on `button_click` then you should write your code in `button_click` event.

Call the package on button_click. This way the package is not executed every time you type something into textbox.

**Edit**

Your `pkg` object is null that why you are getting that error. Move the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables myVars = pkg.Variables;` part after you load the the package.

```
pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables myVars = pkg.Variables;
```

---

```
private void button_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string theText = textBox1.Text;
    string pkgLocation;
    Package pkg = null;
    Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app;
    DTSExecResult pkgResults;
    pkgLocation =
    @"C:\Users\Visual Studio 2008\Projects" +
    @"\Integration Services Project1\xyz.dtsx";
    app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
    pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);

    Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables myVars = pkg.Variables;  

    myVars["Account_number"].Value = theText;

    pkgResults = pkg.Execute(null, myVars,null,null,null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @ElectricRouge. I am getting error on this line  Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables myVars = pkg.Variables;
as NULLREFERENCEEXCEPTION WAS UNHANDLED & Object reference not set to an instance of an object. As i am newbie to .net can you please help me what the issue might be?

Comment: @user2941762 move the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables myVars = pkg.Variables;` part after the `pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);` see edited answer