# "Parameter does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions" when running SSIS package in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, ssis, etl

I have a SSIS package with a bunch of variables, listed below:
[image]

I am trying to call the SSIS package from a C# Windows Form App using the code below:

```
// Create a connection to the server
string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=BSQL_01;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

// Create the Integration Services object
IntegrationServices integrationServices = new IntegrationServices(sqlConnection);

// Get the Integration Services catalog
Catalog catalog = integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"];

// Get the folder
CatalogFolder folder = catalog.Folders["PORGPackages"];

// Get the project
ProjectInfo project = folder.Projects["PORGPackages"];

// Get the package
PackageInfo package = project.Packages["POHandler.dtsx"];

// Add project parameter
Collection<PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet> executionParameter = new Collection<PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet>();
executionParameter.Add(new PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet { ObjectType = 20, ParameterName = "SessionID", ParameterValue = "636943168325507712" });

// Run the package
long executionIdentifier = package.Execute(false, null, executionParameter);

ExecutionOperation executionOperation = integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"].Executions[executionIdentifier];

while (!executionOperation.Completed) {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    executionOperation.Refresh();
    MessageBox.Show("Running...");
}

if (executionOperation.Status == Operation.ServerOperationStatus.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine("Success");
} else if (executionOperation.Status == Operation.ServerOperationStatus.Failed) {
    Console.WriteLine("Failed");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Something Went Really Wrong");
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> The parameter 'SessionID' does not exist or you do not have sufficient
>   permissions.

Am I adding the parameter correctly?  I don't know I can watch to see if it's being set, or if I have permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I adding the parameter correctly?

**You have declared a variable called @SessionID not a parameter.**

If you need to pass a variable value then you can refer to the following link:

- [How to pass variables to an SSIS package from a C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098677/how-to-pass-variables-to-an-ssis-package-from-a-c-sharp-application)

For more information about both objects *(variables & parameters)* you can refer to the following articles:

- [Getting Started with Parameters, Variables & Configurations in SSIS 2012](https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2013/9/15/getting-started-with-parameters-variables-configurations-in.html)
- [What's the difference between Variable and Parameters](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3def40e9-3710-4723-93e5-e057376230e4/whats-the-difference-between-variable-and-parameters?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [SSIS Variables vs Parameters (SSIS Denali)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15337431/ssis-variables-vs-parameters-ssis-denali/48904293)

Comment: Ugh, stupid mistake.  Added it as a PACKAGE Parameter, and updated the ObjectType to 20 and it works.  Now I'm getting a COMPLETELY DIFFERENT error! :(